# Как можно задать разные значения grid-gap в сетке?

Tags: html, css

Для первой колонки например 30px, а для второй 60px.

Answer (score 1):

Самым простым и понятным (с точки зрения поддержки) способом будет сделать это при помощи дополнительных колонок и/или рядов (для рядов):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 30px 100px 60px 100px;
}

.col {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, логику понял